# Ideal way to store large data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a web-based game that involves purchasing property, then rooms inside that property and finally assets. My current way of storing data is having one array containing property purchased (in ID form), then it compares that ID to another array which will list the rooms, then finally another array for the assets inside that room.

However, after recently being introduced to 2D arrays, I'm unsure about which method would be best for storing this data; having multiple arrays that store separate data, or having all of the property data inside one huge 4D array?

Comment: 2d arrays?  I'm guessing that you want a true database to persist them. I would always prefer encapsulation to arrays. Make it clear that "these things belong together".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you using a database and fetching only the data which is currently needed? If you need more data then query again and add it to your arrays. I don't think that the user will run through all rooms in the first attempt.

Or could you give a example on your data/model?

Comment: Sorry, I plan on using ajax for storing the data when the user saves or attempts to close the browser (opposed to storing the data in a database and calling every time a small change is made). Because of this the only option I can find is arrays. The data is mainly ID's, example here: http://pastebin.com/af8KhHWk

Comment: But your data comes from a database? And you want to load it once when use pens game and save it when user closes game? I would not go this way. Instead and as i wrote before load it partially into multiple arrays. But if you would like to go your way, then use multiple arrays.

Comment: Yes, loading it when the game opens sounds good. I'm pretty inexperienced with ajax so I hope this will work! Thanks for the help.